# why does the hover selector not working in span?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**the html code**

```
<div className="header__menuToggle">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

i want to change it's color each time mouse hovering it

**the css code**

this is the css code that make the span looks like hamburger menu

```
.header__menuToggle > span {
    display: block;
    width: 33px;
    height: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 1;
    transform-origin: 4px 0px;
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
                background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
                opacity 0.55s ease;
}

.header__menuToggle > span:hover {
    background-color: #FE8324 !important;
}
```

[this is the hamburger menu in the navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmNGO.png)

the hamburger menu should change into somewhat orange color each time mouse hover, however it is not working

Comment: `className="header__menuToggle"` change to  `class="header__menuToggle"`

Comment: `className` is the name of the property in JavaScript. The attribute in the DOM is `class`.

Comment: Are you want change background in all span while hover the div?

Comment: This code would make each span (white horizontal bar) change color independently when hovered. Is this what you currently have? If you wanted to have the three to change colors, then you'd have to add the hover rule on the parent element, not on the spans

Comment: i want to change each span individual color while hover not the entire div, because i got other component also in the div "header__menuToggle"

Answer (score 1):

- `className="` should be `class="`
- Attach the CSS `:hover` to the parent.

```css
.header__menuToggle>span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), opacity 0.55s ease;
}

.header__menuToggle:hover > span {
  background-color: #FE8324 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__menuToggle">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think className is just because they are using react

Comment: If that was the problem, the non hover rules wouldn't match either.

Answer (score -1):

According your markup structure and your expectation you need slightly change your `CSS` selector when hovering. Because your current approach `.header__menuToggle > span:hover` targeting only single `span` element out of three and not considering rest of the other's two element.

Please just apply following way:

```
.header__menuToggle:hover > span {
    background-color: #FE8324 !important;
}
```